# Prepend value in my text box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, phonegap

I am facing an issue in Samsung device in my hybrid app, When I get a text box value and replace with some other value on keyup event, it is prepended with existing value.

ex:

```
cd = that.$('#id').val(); // cd = 'abc'
$('#id').val(cd+"xyz");
o/p: xyzabcxyz
```

Any one have a solution please let me know.

Comment: Why does it not work? To be honest, I do not understand your example neither

Comment: dupicated question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44714469/prepend-my-textbox-value-with-existing-value#44714469 @Alexander how to close dup question